# Update an object after session.commit() in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Does **updating** an object after issuing `session.commit()` works correctly? Or do I need to refresh the object?

I think this is sufficient for the question, but I may provide more information to clear my question if needed.

Edit:

By updating, I meant setting some attribute i.e. column values of the object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, you do not need to refresh manually, sqlalchemy will do it for you.

---

It is useful to know when it happens, so below is short overview.
From documentation of [`Session.commit()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit):

> By default, the Session also expires all database loaded state on all
>   ORM-managed attributes after transaction commit. This so that
>   subsequent operations load the most recent data from the database.
>   This behavior can be disabled using the expire_on_commit=False option
>   to sessionmaker or the Session constructor.

Basically, given you did not set `expire_on_commit=False`, object will be refreshed automatically as soon as you try accessing (reading, not setting) its attributes after `session.commit()`.

```
my_obj = session.query(MyType).get(1)
my_obj.field1 = 'value1'
session.commit() # will commit and expire my_obj

my_obj.field1 = 'new value' # object is still the same, but field is updated
print my_obje.field1 # at this point SA will first refresh the object from the database; and make sure that new values for changed fields are applied
```

In fact, if you enable logging, you will see that `sqlalchemy` emits new `SELECT` statements as soon as you access (read) persistant instances' attributes.

Comment: I think you misread me? I'm asking about **updating** an object, that is updating one/some column values. Can you please clarify because I think my choice of the word 'updating' could be misleading.

Comment: Ok, this is not the same my answer covers, but large part of it is still relevant. So, basically, after the line in my answer (`my_obj.field1 = 'new value'`), only in memory will this change happen. in order to have you database reflecting this change, you will have to call `session.commmit()` once again. Does this cover it?

Comment: @van I'm experiencing the exact opposite, setting an attribute after the `session.commit()` still updates the database with that new attribute, even though I do not run a `session.commit()` after. So it seems perhaps something change even in regards to updating in the later versions?

Comment: @AndreasKlintberg, this is very strange and i would not expect this behavior to have changed. Just a guess: any chance you are running inside the "context manager" which auto-commits on exit unless there are errors? For, example, flask-sqlalchemy would do this for the web requests sessions.

Comment: Yes sorry I messed up. Wasn't using the correct session :/ thanks for helping out though!

And yes you are right, it was auto-committing as well using sqlalchemy-graphene :)