# Updating a record in SQLAlchemy using session.commit() in a Flask session

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, commit

I'm trying to update a record (row) in SQLAlchemy.  I've been following along with the explanation in this question: [How to update SQLAlchemy row entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667138/how-to-update-sqlalchemy-row-entry) and it seems pretty straightforward, but just is not working for me.
Following this question: [Update an object after session.commit() in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343857/update-an-object-after-session-commit-in-sqlalchemy), I also used `expire_on_commit=False`, but to no avail.

This question addresses the issue of adding a record instead of modifying a record: [A Flask-SQLAlchemy update is creating a new record in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834896/a-flask-sqlalchemy-update-is-creating-a-new-record-in-mysql).  This question addresses moving records from one table to another: [Replace existing records in SQLAlchemy Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438011/replace-existing-records-in-sqlalchemy-core).  Neither of those two questions address my problem.

First I pull the record from the database:

```
>>>first_record = db.session.query(LPRRank).get(1)
```

Then I check it in my session:

```
>>>first_record
M. Misty || None || 1
```

All looks good, so I enter a value for the missing field:

```
>>>first_record.riding = 'South Riding'
```

Check the record again:

```
>>>first_record
M. Misty || South Riding || 1
```

I like what I see, so I commit it to the database:

```
>>>db.session.commit()
```

Apparently, I am missing something because now I lose the value for the riding:

```
>>>first_record
M. Misty || None || 1
```

I lose the value I entered even when I do another query:

```
>>>first_record = db.session.query(LPRRank).get(1)
>>>first_record
M. Misty || None || 1
```

Still not working even when I use `expire_on_commit=False`:

```
>>>first_record = db.session.query(LPRRank).get(1)
>>>first_record
M. Misty || None || 1 
>>>first_record.riding = 'South Riding'
>>>first_record
M. Misty || South Riding || 1 
>>>expire_on_commit=False       <--------- right here
>>>db.session.commit()
>>>first_record = db.session.query(LPRRank).get(1)
>>>first_record
M. Misty || None || 1
```

So my question:
What do I need to do to make a permanent change to the database?

---

Here's the model I'm working with:

```
class LPRRank(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    candid = db.Column(db.String(40), index=True, unique=False)
    riding = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique=False)
    rank = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return '{} || {} || {}'.format(self.candid, self.riding, self.rank)
```

And how I construct my session from my main module:

```
from app import db
from app.models import LPRRank
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'LPRRank': LPRRank}
```

and my `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

Comment: It seems like your approach should work, perhaps try querying by "LPRank.query.order_by(LPRank.id).first()". get(1) would return the object by its primary key, which you might or might not want

Comment: For what it's worth, `>>>expire_on_commit=False       <--------- right here` simply creates a new variable called `expire_on_commit`. It doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @Tobias, thanks.  Your suggestion returns the same empty field for the 'riding' column.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks.  I saw that in the other questions, but as you pointed out, it does nothing.

Comment: You're not adding the change to the `commit` call. Add `db.session.add(first_record)` before `db.session.commit()` and then check the record.